# Precisely combining two meshes

Tags: vertices, transforms, origin

My question regarding Blender is: How can I move one object onto another object by selecting two vertices on each object that should be the same position?
My current solution is to set the object origins to the two vertices where I want to "merge" the objects. Then I copy the XYZ coordinates from one object to the other. That works but is very time consuming for a lot of objects. Is there a more efficient way? Maybe a Plugin or something like that? Ideally I would like to be able to just select the two vertices and then hit a button...

I currently play around with RenderDoc and the possibility to get 3D data directly from Google Maps (for personal use/ fun).
I wanted to get a larger area so I had to make multiple exports.
Now I have multiple meshes in Blender that have partly the same geometry. My plan now is to combine the different "scans" into one big object.

I hope my question was somewhat understandable!

Here are two screenshots two illustrate the problem:

[image: problem]
[image: goal]

Comment: Can you post some screenshots of what you have already tried and what your desired outcome is? As it stands your question could have a number of answers and it's hard to tell what your end goal is.

Comment: If the topology between the objects is identical in the areas where they should overlap, then [snapping](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/controls/snapping.html) should work well. Have you tried this approach? If you are retrieving the data programmatically, you might also want to look into Python scripting to automatically align the chunks, if you have the necessary data to determine how they should be aligned to each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Snap to Vertex** should do the job ... it looks a bit jumpy, but if you switch to edit mode, move all vertices "close" to desired location (not exactly) and move it again from this close position it snaps vertex to vertex you aim to.

[image]

Or ... If you want to avoid jumps, you can do first step (move vertices closer) without snapping enabled and enable snapping for final move by pressing shortcut **Ctrl**.

[image]